# Unity 3d - Change texture by clicking

Tags: unity-game-engine, click, textures, paint, swap

i'm new on Unity and i could use a hand. What i wanna do is:

On my "Render" i will have:

For example, a 3d pyramid, each face owns a difference material/id. 
And i have 6 textures, 6 buttons.

What i wanna do is,
Select one texture by clicking on one of those 6 buttons, and swap/paint the actual pyramid texture to the button texture. I wanna do it, how many times i want it. Like a color book for kids to paint. But they choose the color first, and then where they gonna color.

If i wasn't clear enough, Please ask it.
Thanks for your support!

Comment: Is there some code you can share that provides a [minimal, complete verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: No, there isnt. I only could make the texture swap by clicking on a button. 
 But that is not what i want. @spacepickle

Comment: I think I see - Are you asking how to build the interface for a user to select one of the faces of the pyramid?

Comment: Kind of yeah. imagin:

I have A B C D E F -  Textures;
and i have 1 2 3 - Surfaces of the object ( each one is a material );


I wanna press a Letter (texture), C for example, and i wanna put it on number 3, the surface of the object. And if i want it too, i wanna put it on the number 2. Then i dont want that texture to be there. So i press the Texture B and put it on the number 2... all over again.

Comment: Forgot the identify you @spacepickle

Comment: Maeby this help you understanding me @MukeshSaini

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to store materials in an array -

```
public Material[] materials
```

Then, on click of any button store its index to access material from materials array. For eg., `buttonIndex = 2`.

Now you can use MeshRenderer component of Pyramid Face on which the selected material needs to be applied -

```
GameObject pyramidFace1;
...
pyramidFace1.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[buttonIndex];
...
```

Comment: First, Thanks for your help. But another question as come. I still dont know how the part of the "click" works. As i said, im new on unity. @Mukesh Saini